# How to DRY up .NET webforms wrappers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, webforms

Massive edits:

So, I have refactored an ASP.NET code behind into a Presenter to unit test. After finishing this up, I have noticed that the wrappers I have made to allow this have a lot of duplication that I would like to eliminate. My idea was to use class inheritance to abstract that duplication, but I can't figure it out. An example of what I currently have:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PresenterTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethodTest()
    {
        var fooMock = Mock<IFooWrapper>();
        var fooMock2 = Mock<IFooWrapper>();
        var barMock = Mock<IBarWrapper>();
        var barMock2 = Mock<IBarWrapper>();

        fooMock.Setup(x => x.Baz()).Returns(fooMock2);
        barMock.Setup(x => x.Baz()).Returns(bazMock2);
    }
}

public interface IFooWrapper
{
    IFooWrapper Baz();
}

public class FooWrapper : IFooWrapper
{
    private Foo _instance;

    public FooWrapper(Foo instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public IFooWrapper Baz()
    {
        return new FooWrapper(_instance);
    }
}

public interface IBarWrapper
{
    void Baz();
}

public class BarWrapper : IBarWrapper
{
    private Bar _instance;

    public BarWrapper(Bar instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public IBarWrapper Baz()
    {
        return new BarWrapper(_instance);
    }
}
```

Based on what Steve Harris was saying below based on my very poor communication, I currently have the following that seems close but not quite there:

```
public interface IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where TWrapper: IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where T : class
{
    TWrapper Baz();
}

public class BaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> : IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where TWrapper : BaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where T : class
{
    public T Instance;

    public BaseWrapper()
    {
    }

    public BaseWrapper(T instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }

    public TWrapper Baz()
    {
        return new TWrapper(Instance);
    }
}

public interface IFooWrapper : IBaseWrapper<FooWrapper, Foo>
{
}

public class FooWrapper : BaseWrapper<FooWrapper, Foo>, IFooWrapper
{
    public FooWrapper() {}
    public FooWrapper(T instance) : base(instance) {}
}

public interface IBarWrapper : IBaseWrapper<BarWrapper, Bar>
{
}

public class BarWrapper : BaseWrapper<BarWrapper, Bar>, IBarWrapper
{
    public BarWrapper() {}
    public BarWrapper(T instance) : base(instance) {}
}
```

Comment: From your example, it is not clear at all how this relates to web forms. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don;t think you need generics here.  Looks like you're implementing the Decorator pattern.  Try the same code without the generics, and use IBaseWrapper in place of T for _instance.  Also, there's probably no need to inherit from BaseWrapper

Comment: @NightOwl888 - I suppose I can remove the "webforms" and "ASP.Net" from the description, it's really a general wrapper inheritance question really, but it seemed like people who have had to deal with unit-testing this stuff are the ones most likely to know the answer.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. It is hard to give advice on whether generics are the right choice without more context in the question. You don't need to create a huge sample or even a real-world one, just something to demonstrate the problem you are solving with enough context to understand why you are making the design choices you are.

Comment: Yeah, I'm very new to C# and jumping straight into this legacy weirdness, so I don't know how to ask what I'm trying to ask. Trying to figure that out. :)

Comment: @NightOwl888 I edited my post rather a lot to include more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these the constraints you're looking for?

```
public interface IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, T>
{
    TWrapper Baz();
}

public class BaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> : IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where TWrapper : BaseWrapper<TWrapper, T> where T : class
{
    private T _instance;

    public BaseWrapper(T instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public TWrapper Baz()
    {
        // note whatever wrapper class you are using must have a
        // constructor matching this base class
        return Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(), new object[] { _instance });
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public void FooSpecificMethod()
    {
        // foo stuff
    }
}

public interface IFooWrapper<TWrapper> : IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, Foo> where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper<TWrapper, Foo>
{
    void FooSpecificMethod();
}

public class FooWrapper : BaseWrapper<FooWrapper, Foo>, IFooWrapper<FooWrapper>
{
    public FooWrapper(Foo instance) : base(instance)
    {
    }

    public void FooSpecificMethod()
    {
        instance.FooSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although, you probably don't need the <T> on the interface as you have defined it. I guess you may have more generic methods defined in your actual interface.

Comment: On the one hand, this seems like it's close. On the other hand, it doesn't give me what I am trying to do, which is to Moq IFooWrapper in a unit test and do IFooWrapper.Setup(x => x.Baz()). I apologize for not being clear in my OP. IFooWrapper and IBarWrapper are mostly different, but they have a few duplications that pain me, particularly since those methods are duplicated in other wrappers as well. :)

Also, you appear to have an error in your BaseWrapper declaration: BaseWrapper<T>. As least, changing that is what got rid of the error for me, but I might have done it wrong.

Comment: Ok, so are you looking for interface inheritance? I have edited the answer.

Comment: I just edited my original post significantly to better explain what I'm trying to do. I'll go ahead and see what I can do with your changes. :)

Comment: What you said is indeed what I'm trying to do, however I left out the fact that Baz has type specific functionality.

Comment: ok, on checking your changes, my last edit was mostly nonsense. How about this?

Comment: I've just updated the IFooWrapper interface and FooWrapper class so that the error you mentioned shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

you probably use a [factory method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) implementation.

```
public class BaseWrapper
{
    public virtual void Baz()
    {
       // Do some shared work
    }
}

public class BarWrapper : BaseWrapper
{
    private Bar _instance;

    public BarWrapper(Bar instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public override void Baz()
    {
        base.Baz();
        // Do custom stuff for this wrapper type?
    }
}
```

I usually lead with a Generic implementation when im trying to build a piece of code that can handle doing processing on some collection of objects that inherit a shared interface public class IFileParser where IFileImplementation could be all kinds of stuff.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, the point is that there is only shared work. I'm trying to avoid mentioning Baz in the child.

Answer (score 0):

From your example code, it looks like generics are not necessary.  You are possibly implementing the Decorator pattern though.

This example illustrates a non-generics version of your code.  Is this what you're after?

```
public interface IBazzer
{
    void Baz();
}

public class TheBaz : IBazzer
{
    public void Baz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
public class Wrapper : IBazzer
{
    private IBazzer _instance;

    public Wrapper(IBazzer instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public void Baz()
    {
        // do stuff before calling the wrapped Bazzer
        this.PreBaz();

        _instance.Baz();

        // do stuff after calling the wrapped Bazzer        
        this.PostBaz();
    }

    protected virtual void PreBaz(){}
    protected virtual void PostBaz(){}
}

public class FooWrapper : Wrapper
{
    public FooWrapper(IBazzer wrapped):base(wrapped){}

    protected override void PreBaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo Pre Baz");
    }
    protected override void PostBaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo Post Baz");
    }

}

public class BarWrapper : Wrapper
{
    public BarWrapper(IBazzer wrapped):base(wrapped){}

    protected override void PreBaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar Pre Baz");
    }
    protected override void PostBaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar Post Baz");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var x = new     TheBaz();
    var y = new FooWrapper(x);

    y.Baz(); 
    // Foo Pre Baz
    // Hello World
    // Foo Post Baz
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that I need to be able to mock Baz with either IFooWrapper or IBarWrapper.